# What The variable find exactly is doing here?

Tags: c, sorting, boolean, command-line-arguments, bubble-sort

This a program to compare arguments and sorts them lexicographically. Can you please explain what `find` is doing there and how it affects the code? I see this kind of model in a lot of code; its value varies between 1 and 0 in the while, so can you clarify please.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char *tmp;
    int find;
    int i;

    find = 1;
    while (find)
    {
        find = 0;
        i = 0;
        while (++i < argc - 1)
        {
            if (strcmp(argv[i], argv[i + 1]) > 0)
            {
                tmp = argv[i];
                argv[i] = argv[i + 1];
                argv[i + 1] = tmp;
                find = 1;
            }
        }
    }
    i = 0;
    while (++i < argc)
        printf("%s\n", argv[i]);
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: `find` is a **flag** used to stop the loop iterating once its job is done. When the code block under `strcmp` does not execute, `find` remains `0` and so the outer loop does not continue.

Comment: Change the name of the variable `find` to `made_a_change` everywhere it appears, and the code will make a little more sense.  (When it makes it all the way through without having to change anything, it's done.)

Comment: `while (find)` will run the loop body iff `find` is not evaluated to zero. It's a simple boolean variable.

Comment: I assume this is just some kind of teaching program, but please be aware that (1) writing a program to manipulate its own argument list in this way is a rather strange thing to do, and (2) the "[bubble sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort)" algorithm which this program uses, although it's simple and easy to understand, turns out to be a pretty terrible way to actually do sorting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code snippet

```
find = 1;
while (find)
{
    find = 0;
    i = 0;
    while (++i < argc - 1)
    {
        if (strcmp(argv[i], argv[i + 1]) > 0)
        {
            tmp = argv[i];
            argv[i] = argv[i + 1];
            argv[i + 1] = tmp;
            find = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

implements the bubble sort algorithm.

Initially, it is supposed that command line arguments are not sorted as strings.

```
find = 1;
```

Then within the while loop, the flag `find` is reset to 0.

```
    find = 0;
```

If within the inner while loop

```
while (++i < argc - 1)
{
        if (strcmp(argv[i], argv[i + 1]) > 0)
        {
            tmp = argv[i];
            argv[i] = argv[i + 1];
            argv[i + 1] = tmp;
            find = 1;
        }
}
```

there is found an argument (string) that is greater than the next argument (string)

```
        if (strcmp(argv[i], argv[i + 1]) > 0)
```

then the adjacent arguments are swapped and the flag `find` is set to `1` that signals that the array of arguments is not yet sorted (we need at least one more iteration of the outer while loop to check whether all arguments are indeed sorted after this swapping).